# Christianity "fish" badge appears in list of new badges for non-Christianity Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, design

When I look at my list of Stack Exchange achievements on most sites, I see a colored dot indicating that I have earned a new badge. Here is what it looks like on Stack Overflow (and every other site I have tried):

[image]

However, when I look at the same list of achievements on Christianity Stack Exchange, I see the "fish" (Icthus) badge, even for non-Christianity sites.

[image]

It seems like a bug to have a Christian fish badge for a question about Superman and Spider-Man.

The same thing happens in reverse for Christianity badges too. On Stack Overflow, it looks like this:

[image]

But on Christianity Stack Exchange, it looks like this:

[image]

Can we possibly fix this so that the achievements list always shows the proper badge icon for the site? So no matter what site you are on, the fish icon appears for Christianity badges and the default icon appears for non-Christianity badges?

Comment: This might be an matter of economy: loading the style sheet and icon set for one site is one thing, but loading _all the styles and icons_ for all the sites when you visit just one site might be a bit of a stretch. I suspect this isn't a Christianity.SE specific issue. Did you review any sites that came custom (non dot) shapes for their local badges? Maybe making this menu dots all the time no matter what the local site style is would make sense.

Comment: @Caleb, yes, this does seem to happen on Academia. SE as well, which uses a mortarboard for a badge. Dots all the time would be a good alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an issue on all Stack Exchange sites, not just Christianity.SE.  So the best place to report it would actually be Meta.SE, and indeed, it has been reported there a number of times:

- [Badge symbol in notification is of the site you're on, not where badge was earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233517/300411)

The best thing to do is upvote that question and hope that it eventually makes the developers' to-do list.  And if you want, install the user script that's provided in the answer to that question.

Comment: I always figured this was [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. After all, a badge is a badge is a badge. Never occurred to me to consider it a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: One person's status-bydesign is another person's bug :)